# Why isn't this code working

Tags: autohotkey

This one works:

```
CapsLock::(
```

but this one doesn't:

```
CapsLock::(
+CapsLock::CapsLock
```

I want a bracket when I press the capslock button, but I also want the native capslock action when pressing it while holding shift! I'll be doing the same thing (but with the opposite bracket) using the "\" key, also not working.

I'm using authotkey v1.0.48.05

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
+CapsLock::CapsLock
$CapsLock::(
```

B.t.w. what I did to access ( and ) without shift is:

```
:?*:[[::(
:?*:]]::)
```

Here I press [ or ] twice to get ( or )